# Calculating the powers of 2 in a tail-recursive way

Tags: f#

I am trying to implement a tail-recursive function that calculates the powers of 2:

```
let rec po2 x =
    match x with
    | 1 -> 1I
    | _ -> po2 (x-1) * 2I
```

This works like intended, but since i multiply my recursive calls result by 2 this code isn't tail recursive.

Any ideas on how to make this tail recursive?

Comment: Although your question isn't really about memoization, perhaps it's useful to note that you are not actually caching anything in this example. Also, in cases where the indices will be (unsigned) integers and the cache will always contain a full range, you can more efficiently store the cache as a list.

Comment: My bad, i cut that part while cropping my original function to post here. Actually I will remove the whole memoization part as it unnecessarily complicates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any linearly recursive function can be turned into a tail-recursive one by using an "accumulator" - a thread-through parameter that accumulates the "computed so far" value. In general, you'd be trading stack memory for heap memory (need to store that "so far" value *somewhere*), but in some cases you can save by not storing the *whole* "so far" value, but only a part of it. In your case, all you really need to store is the result of the last multiplication, not the whole history of multiplications:

```
let rec po2Cached acc x =
   match x with 
   | 0 -> acc
   | x -> po2Cached (acc*2l) (x-1)
```

(I've omitted the memoization part for simplicity)

P.S. Note that this function will produce wrong result for negative powers.

Comment: So you basically construct the return value from top-to-bottom instead of bottom-to-top by shifting the calculation into the parameter list?

Comment: @LucaFülbier - A good way to think of recursive functions with accumulators, if you're not used to seeing them yet, is to mentally translate them into a function made of an infinite loop (like a `while true`). Any match condition that calls the function again with new values is like `let acc = acc * 2l ; let x = x - 1 ; continue`, while any match condition that produces a value without calling the tail-recursive function again is like `return (value)`: it ends the loop and exits the function.